# Jython "Attribute not found"

Tags: python, module, tkinter, turtle-graphics, jes

I'm attempting to use some of the tkinter functionality in JES, on v3.4. But I'm getting an error after import.

Code begin with this:

```
import Turtle
import math
myPen = Turtle.turtle()
window = Turtle.screen()
```

Returns the error

> The error was:class 'Turtle' has no attribute 'turtle' 
>   Attribute not found.

(Note I'm on the right version (3.4.3) of python for "Turtle" instead of "turtle")
`import turtle` gives `The error was: turtle (wrong name: Turtle)`

I tried some troubleshooting in the Python console as recommended by a similar thread, the results are below. I believe the output should have been `"turtle.py"` or similar but as you can see, not working.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\python34.zip', 'C:\\Python34\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python34\
\lib', 'C:\\Python34', 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']
>>> import turtle
>>> turtle.__file.__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file'
>>>
```

Following the path `C:\Python34\Lib` I found there is a folder `C:\Python34\Lib\turtledemo` containing file `turtle.cfg` but no `turtle.py` 
Also `C:\Python34\DLLs` contains `_tkinter.pyd` (and many others) but no `_turtle.pyd`

I'm just a student trying to use `turtle` in JES for a project, so I hope this question makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're looking for a screen in the module.  You have to create a turtle object.  That will have a screen attribute.  I'm using CPython 3.5 and `import turtle` works.

```
>>> import turtle
>>> t = turtle.Turtle()
>>> t.screen
<turtle._Screen object at 0x10cd25a20>
```

You may have to modify this on your platform.

Comment: `import Turtle` followed by `myPen = turtle.Turtle()` gives `The error was:class 'Turtle' has no attribute 'Turtle'`    ==== Still the same issue, I've tried all combinations of caps etc... any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I don't.  I don't use JES (nor Jython), and apparently, it's got some differences from CPython that I don't understand.  I've tried Googling, and I haven't found any evidence that a JES turtle even has a screen attribute.

Comment: I'll put it down to limitations in JES. Wasn't an overly important issue anyway. `@saulspatz Thank you for you time on this`